# Как правильно добавлять данные в xlsx через pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет, кто подскажет как через pandas добавлять данные в файл не перезатерая предыдущие записи?
Есть вот такой вот цикл, но в файл попадает только последний продукт

```
for item in product_nodes:
    name = item.find('div', class_='list-filter-result__name').text.strip()
    url_product = item.find('div', class_='list-filter-result__name').find(
        'a').get('href')
    vendor_code = item.find('a', class_='prdct-artcl').text.replace(
        'Код товара:', '').strip()
    try:
        price = item.find('span',
                          class_='list-filter-result-price__valid').text\
            .strip().replace(' ','')
        price = re.findall(r'(^\d+)', price)[0]
    except:
        price = '0'
    df_marks = pd.DataFrame({'артикул': [vendor_code],
                             'наименование': [name],
                             'price': [price],
                             'category': [category],
                             'url': [url_product]})
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
    df_marks.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Comment: Делайте списки, собирайте их в цикле, а в датафрейм преобразуйте и выгружайте в эксель уже после окончания цикла вот эти вот полученные списки.

Comment: @CrazyElf, можешь показать пример или что почитать? не нагуглил, только начинаю знакомство с пандасом

Comment: Вернее, лучше в данном случае собрать список словарей. Я написал как в виде ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так можно собрать в список словарей значения:

```py
data = []
for item in product_nodes:
    # тут ваш код для разбора данных в переменные
    ...
    data.append({'артикул': vendor_code,
                 'наименование': name,
                 'price': price,
                 'category': category,
                 'url': url_product})

# цикл кончился, делаем датафрейм
df_marks = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_marks.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

`Pandas` одинаково нормально воспринимает и список словарей и словарь списков, можно и так и так данные собирать - и в отдельные списки, а потом из них словарь сделать, а можно как тут делать словари и собирать их в список.

P.S. А если всё-таки нужен `ExcelWriter`, то не забывайте использовать менеджер контекста, чтобы файл правильно закрылся:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') as writer:
    df_marks.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я попробовал, но файл создается вообще пустым

Comment: Если что многоточие там - это ваш код, который достаёт значения, надеюсь вы его оставили в цикле? )  Нужно разбираться - цикл вообще отрабатывает? Что в `data` получилось?

Comment: ну да) я понял что там мой код, в дата формируется  список словарей
{'артикул': '0 601 015 000 001', 'наименование': 'Гайковерт Thorvik LSW1 ручной механический 1"DR, 3800 Нм', 'price': '2720', 'category': 'Инструменты > Автотовары', 'url': '/catalog/127133/261609/'},

Comment: Так, а зачем там вообще `ExcelWriter`? Попробуйте просто имя файла указать

Comment: Да, так отработало, а можете обьяснить почему не использовать  ExcelWriter? я читал что он в начале необходимо прочитать и потом записывать, даже в могих примерах используют этот ExcelWriter

Comment: А, наверное проблема была в том, что вы его не закрывали, поэтому пустой файл получался. Я добавил пример, как правильно делать. Если вы хотите какую-то продвинутую работу с экселем - как-то называть листы и т.д. - тогда `ExcelWriter` понадобится, да.

Comment: Спасибо что обьяснили

Comment: @CrazyElf в практике работы с `to_excel()` БЕЗ ExcelWriter у меня возникали непонятные артефакты в виде "обрезания" некоторых, не всегда тех же самых, строк в одном и том же фрейме. После переделки под ExcelWriter артефакты исчезли. Причину я так и не понял, вроде бы движок записи в Excel тот же самый, но факт есть факт.

Comment: @АлексейР, а вот не знаешь как обойти блокировку в экселе на запись больше 65к улов, или как можно сделать так чтоб пандас не конвертировал url в url, а просто оставлял строкой?

Comment: @Ruin можно добавить апостроф или пробел перед URL: `df.URLS = " "+df.URLS`

Comment: @АлексейР, спасибо я попробую